# WP Rig - How can I filter posts by category

Tags: php, wordpress

In the WP Rig system, I've created a custom content template in order to have some pages display posts from a specific category. I've done this many times successfully in the past, but the coding that I've used is not working in the WP Rig system. Here is the coding that I've used:

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=12', '&category_name=reviews'); ?> <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?> <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?></a> <h3 class="home-post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3> <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
```

This creates errors in the WP Rig system. Here is the code that works in WP Rig:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'entry' ); ?>> <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content/entry_header', get_post_type() ); if ( is_search() ) { get_template_part( 'template-parts/content/entry_summary', get_post_type() ); } else { get_template_part( 'template-parts/content/entry_content', get_post_type() ); } get_template_part( 'template-parts/content/entry_footer', get_post_type() ); ?> </article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```

I just need to somehow filter this by category and limit the posts to 12.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer - found this on GitHub:

Because WP_Query is a class, you need to include "use WP_Query;" in your template. So now your front-page.php should look something like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Render your site front page, whether the front page displays the blog posts index or a static page.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#front-page-display
 *
 * @package wp_rig
 */

namespace WP_Rig\WP_Rig;
use WP_Query;

get_header();

etc....
```